# Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop. React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

so i try to render an array of object into react js component like below:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

import { Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";

import {
  MdOutlineSpaceDashboard,
  MdOutlineStorage,
  MdOutlineFactCheck,
  MdOutlineCalculate,
  MdStickyNote2,
  MdAssignmentTurnedIn,
  MdOutlineDynamicForm,
  MdOutlineArrowDropDown,
} from "react-icons/md";
import { BsChevronDown, BsArrowLeftShort } from "react-icons/bs";

import Logo_Nabati from "../assets/logo-nabati.svg";

const menuItems = [
  { id: 1, label: "Dashboard", icon: MdOutlineSpaceDashboard, link: "/" },
  {
    id: 2,
    label: "Master Data",
    icon: MdOutlineStorage,
    iconArrow: MdOutlineArrowDropDown,
    link: "",
    subMenu: true,
    subMenuItems: [
      { id: 1, label: "KSBT", link: "/MasterData/list/KSBT" },
      { id: 2, label: "SQ01_RM", link: "/MasterData" },
      { id: 3, label: "SQ01_PM", link: "/MasterData" },
      { id: 4, label: "Depre", link: "/MasterData" },
      { id: 5, label: "OMC", link: "/MasterData" },
      { id: 6, label: "Premix", link: "/MasterData" },
      { id: 7, label: "Routing", link: "/MasterData" },
      { id: 8, label: "MP", link: "/MasterData" },
    ],
  },
  { id: 3, label: "Check COGM", icon: MdOutlineFactCheck, link: "/checkcogm" },
  {
    id: 4,
    label: "Calculation",
    icon: MdOutlineCalculate,
    link: "/calculation",
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    label: "Draft Calculation",
    icon: MdStickyNote2,
    link: "/draft",
  },
  { id: 6, label: "Approved", icon: MdAssignmentTurnedIn, link: "/approval" },
  { id: 7, label: "Task Activity", icon: MdOutlineDynamicForm, link: "/task" },
];

const Sidebar = () => {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const [submenuOpen, setSubmenuOpen] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div className="flex">
      <div
        className={` bg-yellow-400 h-screen p-5 pt-8  ${
          open
            ? "w-50 ease-out delay-150 peer-focus:left-0 duration-200"
            : "w-20 ease-out delay-150 peer-focus:left-0 duration-200"
        } duration-300 relative`}
      >
        <BsArrowLeftShort
          className={` bg-white text-yellow-300 text-3xl rounded-full absolute -right-3 top-9 border border-yellow-300 cursor-pointer delay-150 duration-200  ${
            !open && "rotate-180"
          }`}
          onClick={() => setOpen(!open)}
        />
        <div className={`inline-flex`}>
          <img src={Logo_Nabati} width={123} height={75} alt="logo Nabati" />
        </div>
        <ul className="pt-8">
          {menuItems.map(
            ({ icon: Icon, iconArrow: IconArrow, ...menu }, index) => (
              <>
                <Link to={menu.link}>
                  <li
                    key={index}
                    className="text-white text-sm text-justify flex items-center gap-x-4 cursor-pointer p-2 hover:bg-red-600 rounded-md mt-2"
                  >
                    <Icon className="text-2xl text-white group-hover:text-red-600" />

                    <span
                      className={`text-base font-mendium flex-1 duration-200 ${
                        !open && "hidden"
                      } `}
                    >
                      {menu.label}
                    </span>
                    {menu.subMenu && (
                      <BsChevronDown
                        className={`text-base font-mendium  duration-200 ${
                          !open && "hidden"
                        } ${submenuOpen && "rotate-180"}`}
                        onClick={() => {
                          setSubmenuOpen(!submenuOpen);
                        }}
                      />
                    )}
                  </li>{" "}
                </Link>
                {menu.subMenu && submenuOpen && open && (
                  <ul>
                    {menu.subMenuItems.map((subMenuItem, index) => (
                      <Link to={subMenuItem.link}>
                        <li
                          key={index}
                          className="text-white text-sm flex items-center gap-x-4 cursor-pointer p-1 px-12 hover:bg-red-500 rounded-md"
                        >
                          {subMenuItem.label}
                        </li>{" "}
                      </Link>
                    ))}
                  </ul>
                )}
              </>
            )
          )}
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Sidebar;
```

even after i put the key={index} on the

component i still got warning like this

```
react-jsx-dev-runtime.development.js:119 Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.
```

can someone tell me where di i do wrong here, it supposed to be no problem after i put the key={item} but why i still gettingn error on the console?

Comment: Move `key={index}` from `li` tag to `Link` tag like `<Link to={menu.link} key={index}` . Same like wherever you use `map` method. Because the key attribute needs to be assigned to the immediate first child element of the parent.

Comment: still the same problem here.. @M

Comment: Did you made the same change here as well for `subMenuItem` like`<Link to={subMenuItem.link} key={index}>` ?

Comment: yes i have made it there also

Comment: Can you try changing the name of index in submenu to some other name may be **j** like, `menu.subMenuItems.map((subMenuItem, j) => (`  and give key to submenu link like `<Link to={subMenuItem.link} key={index-j}` ?

Comment: hmmm why it still give the same error on that... i really dont get it where did i do wrong

Comment: Done, we forget the empty tag <></> that the first element actually

Comment: Yes I am mean to say about the empty tag but you find it out good. Give some tag name instead of empty tag and move the key there.

Comment: adding extra dom elements for simply adding a `key` prop is quite a bad practice. Instead you can just put it directly on the fragment, although I believe you need to write out the name vs the shorthand `<>`. I.e. `<Fragment key={index}>`. where `Fragment` is imported from react. `import {Fragment} from 'react'`

Comment: @JohnRuddell, Agree with you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do the following

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

import { Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";

import {
  MdOutlineSpaceDashboard,
  MdOutlineStorage,
  MdOutlineFactCheck,
  MdOutlineCalculate,
  MdStickyNote2,
  MdAssignmentTurnedIn,
  MdOutlineDynamicForm,
  MdOutlineArrowDropDown,
} from "react-icons/md";
import { BsChevronDown, BsArrowLeftShort } from "react-icons/bs";

import Logo_Nabati from "../assets/logo-nabati.svg";

const menuItems = [
  { id: 1, label: "Dashboard", icon: MdOutlineSpaceDashboard, link: "/" },
  {
    id: 2,
    label: "Master Data",
    icon: MdOutlineStorage,
    iconArrow: MdOutlineArrowDropDown,
    link: "",
    subMenu: true,
    subMenuItems: [
      { id: 1, label: "KSBT", link: "/MasterData/list/KSBT" },
      { id: 2, label: "SQ01_RM", link: "/MasterData" },
      { id: 3, label: "SQ01_PM", link: "/MasterData" },
      { id: 4, label: "Depre", link: "/MasterData" },
      { id: 5, label: "OMC", link: "/MasterData" },
      { id: 6, label: "Premix", link: "/MasterData" },
      { id: 7, label: "Routing", link: "/MasterData" },
      { id: 8, label: "MP", link: "/MasterData" },
    ],
  },
  { id: 3, label: "Check COGM", icon: MdOutlineFactCheck, link: "/checkcogm" },
  {
    id: 4,
    label: "Calculation",
    icon: MdOutlineCalculate,
    link: "/calculation",
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    label: "Draft Calculation",
    icon: MdStickyNote2,
    link: "/draft",
  },
  { id: 6, label: "Approved", icon: MdAssignmentTurnedIn, link: "/approval" },
  { id: 7, label: "Task Activity", icon: MdOutlineDynamicForm, link: "/task" },
];

const Sidebar = () => {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const [submenuOpen, setSubmenuOpen] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div className="flex">
      <div
        className={` bg-yellow-400 h-screen p-5 pt-8  ${
          open
            ? "w-50 ease-out delay-150 peer-focus:left-0 duration-200"
            : "w-20 ease-out delay-150 peer-focus:left-0 duration-200"
        } duration-300 relative`}
      >
        <BsArrowLeftShort
          className={` bg-white text-yellow-300 text-3xl rounded-full absolute -right-3 top-9 border border-yellow-300 cursor-pointer delay-150 duration-200  ${
            !open && "rotate-180"
          }`}
          onClick={() => setOpen(!open)}
        />
        <div className={`inline-flex`}>
          <img src={Logo_Nabati} width={123} height={75} alt="logo Nabati" />
        </div>
        <ul className="pt-8">
          {menuItems.map(
            ({ icon: Icon, iconArrow: IconArrow, ...menu }, index) => (
              <div key={menu.id}>
                <Link to={menu.link}>
                  <li
                    className="text-white text-sm text-justify flex items-center gap-x-4 cursor-pointer p-2 hover:bg-red-600 rounded-md mt-2"
                  >
                    <Icon className="text-2xl text-white group-hover:text-red-600" />

                    <span
                      className={`text-base font-mendium flex-1 duration-200 ${
                        !open && "hidden"
                      } `}
                    >
                      {menu.label}
                    </span>
                    {menu.subMenu && (
                      <BsChevronDown
                        className={`text-base font-mendium  duration-200 ${
                          !open && "hidden"
                        } ${submenuOpen && "rotate-180"}`}
                        onClick={() => {
                          setSubmenuOpen(!submenuOpen);
                        }}
                      />
                    )}
                  </li>{" "}
                </Link>
                {menu.subMenu && submenuOpen && open && (
                  <ul>
                    {menu.subMenuItems.map((subMenuItem, index) => (
                      <Link to={subMenuItem.link} key={`${menu.id}-${subMenuItem.id}`}>
                        <li
                          key={index}
                          className="text-white text-sm flex items-center gap-x-4 cursor-pointer p-1 px-12 hover:bg-red-500 rounded-md"
                        >
                          {subMenuItem.label}
                        </li>{" "}
                      </Link>
                    ))}
                  </ul>
                )}
              </div>
            )
          )}
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Sidebar;
```

you need to add the key to the first element inside the map in your code the first element is a fragment

```
<></>
```

that way is not working when you do it on the

```
<li key={index}
```

also avoid to use index it will trigger a warning and is better practice use a unique identifier

Answer (score 1):

A more proper way to handle this issue is to use a `React.Fragment` element. this way you do not pollute your DOM tree with unnecessary wrapper elements. Also in the accepted answer, the DOM tree is adding a `div` in between a `ul` and `li` set. Which is invalid HTML semantics and you'll undoubtedly see errors in the console for this.

```
...

<ul className="pt-8">
  {menuItems.map(({ icon: Icon, iconArrow: IconArrow, ...menu }) => (
    <React.Fragment key={menu.id}>
      ...
    </React.Fragment>
  ))}
</ul>
...
```

One way React optimizes + determines when a component / element needs a new render is with a `key`. You can specify it on any element to give extra control. However, when you are dynamically rendering elements via some form of a loop (i.e. mapping over an array and returning jsx), React needs some extra help knowing how to track the items `key`. This item needs to be the top most element. So this is why it needs to be on the `Fragment`.